# Array tree with parent strings

Tags: php, tree

I have an array list with multiple filenames:

```
Array (
[0] - FILENAME_01.txt,
[1] - FILENAME_02.txt,
[2] - FILENAME_03.txt,
[3] - FILENAME_03_REJ.txt,
[4] - FILENAME_03_REJ_REJ.txt,
[5] - FILENAME_02_REJ.txt
)
```

At times a file may contain others. Example is the  FILENAME_03 which contains FILENAME_03_REJ and another level FILENAME_03_REJ_REJ. I need to display them hierarchically, not looking for "REJ" as it is variable, but if one contains the other. The end result should be:

```
Array (
[0] - "filename" => FILENAME_01.txt, "parent_id" => 0,
[1] - "filename" => FILENAME_02.txt, "parent_id" => 0,
[2] - "filename" => FILENAME_03.txt, "parent_id" => 0,
[3] - "filename" => FILENAME_03_REJ.txt, "parent_id" => 2,
[4] - "filename" => FILENAME_03_REJ_REJ.txt, "parent_id" => 3,
[5] - "filename" => FILENAME_02_REJ.txt, "parent_id" => 1,
)
```

The problem should be solved in PHP.

Comment: What is the specific problem you have with your attempt in solving this problem? Please show us your attempted solution.

Comment: The problem is that I can't solve the problem. I wonder if anyone has any tips.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is below:

```
<?php
$itens = array(
    array('filename' => 'FILENAME_01.txt', 'parent_id' => 0),
    array('filename' => 'FILENAME_02.txt', 'parent_id' => 0),
    array('filename' => 'FILENAME_03.txt', 'parent_id' => 0),
    array('filename' => 'FILENAME_03_REJ.txt', 'parent_id' => 0),
    array('filename' => 'FILENAME_03_REJ_REJ.txt', 'parent_id' => 0),
    array('filename' => 'FILENAME_02_REJ.txt', 'parent_id' => 0),
    array('filename' => 'FILENAME_03_REJ_REJ_REJ.txt', 'parent_id' => 0),
);

foreach($itens as $key1 => $value1){

    $string_replace = str_replace(".txt", "", $value1['filename']);

    foreach($itens as $key => $value){  
        if((preg_match('/'.$string_replace.'/',$value['filename'])) AND ($value['filename'] != $string_replace . '.txt')){
            $itens[$key]['parent_id'] = $key1;
        }
    }
}
print '<pre>';
print_r($itens);
print '</pre>';

?>
```